# Identify this plant with leaves that look like hemlock

Tags: identification, shrubs

This plant is growing in my garden. Its leaves smell lovely when you rub them with your hand.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Two more photos:   [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4aNT.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IShGI.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an other family. Compositae / Asteraceae.

This is one of the Artemisia species, but not the lovely Artemisia absinthium.

Usually they stink, they are invasive, and if you dig, you will see running root that will emerge as new plants everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

[Sagebrush Artemesia](http://www.wnmu.edu/academic/nspages/gilaflora/artemisia_carruthii.html)I agree with Como!  Artemesia carruthii Carruths Sagebrush.  Smells like sage?

Comment: Yes it has a smell like sage but more strong.

Comment: I'd pull it BEFORE it produces seeds...